# Wrmsr command writes value but rdmsr shows the value has not changed

Tags: command-line, lubuntu, overclocking

I have been recently been trying to overclock my old destop computer. It has a Intel Celeron and I and running LUbuntu 15.04. I am trying to to change the vcore value (to allow higher overclock) by adjusting register 0x198 (the last two digits are the current VID correct?).The original settings are:

`rdmsr 0x198; rdmsr 0x199; rdmsr 0x1a0
142b0000142b
142b
20a40089`

My problem is when I write a new value:

```
wrmsr 0x198 142b00001430; rdmsr 0x198
142b0000142b
```

the original value is returned

Is the cpu constantly rewriting this value so by the time the second command is called it has already rewritten the previous value?

this seems the most straightforward way to increase my vcore (since there is no option in my bios). If you know a better way, by all means tell me.

Thanks, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have only known the MSR at 0x198 on Intel processors to be a read only register. It might be different for your particular Intel processor though. And yes, since it is a status MSR, it gets updated constantly.

Comment: Thanks for the response, that would explain my problem. Do you know which is the correct register to change the Vcore voltage?

Comment: I don't know. I only mess with the pstates.

Answer (score 2):

In the paper [Compiler Transformations Meet CPU Clock
Modulation and Power Capping 2016](http://www.cse.psu.edu/conferences/icpppasa2016/wang_slides.pdf), it was mentioned on their slides that you should write a specific value to IA32 CLOCK MODULATION (0x19a)
MSR, so the correct register to change the frequency is 0x19a.

When I write a value like this:

```
sudo wrmsr 0x19a 0x12
```

the original value is not returned and the register is adjusted as `sudo rdmsr 0x19a` gives the output:

> 12